# Why can't I add this .gif the turtle shape in python?

Tags: python, image, turtle-graphics

```
pencil = "/Users/h205p6/Desktop/pencill.gif"
turtle.register_shape(pencil)
turtle.add_shape(pencil)
turtle.shape(pencil)
```

When I try to to run this code I get "pyimage1" does not exist.

I need major help!

If i take away the turtle.add_shape(pencil) i still get the same error code!

Comment: Is there more code than this? Can you give us the exact and complete error message?

Comment: Yeah sure this is exactly what i get! plus a bit more that doesnt fit. this is the main error message!
  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2305, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist